# Array size is less then no of record

Tags: arrays, sorting

Suppose a file contains student’s records with each record containing
name and age of a student. Write a program to read these records and
display them in sorted order by age in descending order.
**Max size of array of structures is 10, and you have more than 10 records
to sort.**

Comment: ok... nice homework.. which part are you having problems with??

Comment: Are you allowed to have more than one array? If not, (only one array allowed), then you need to implement an external type merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dynamically create another array when the elements of previous array are full. For example:
Array A has size 10. And when it contain data in all the consecutive locations, Declare Array B dynamically. You should use the technique of Linked list to solve your problem where you can use "Array of size 10" instead of "single Node".